# Separate JS file, events not working as expected

Tags: jquery, events

I have an external JS file where all the data is loaded,main.js. There is a reset button on my apsx page. The button click event is written in main.js as follows

```
$('#btnReset').on('click', function (event) {
    DefaultValues();
    GetFinalData();
});
```

Similarly I have few other events as well in my `main.js` for different buttons and dropdowns. This file also contains 2 functions `DefaultValues()` and `GetFinalData()` where ajax call is made to get some values and fill the dropdowns and grids on the aspx page.

Now I want to separate all events into separate file say `events.js`. I have placed the reset button click event in this file.

And loaded the JS files as follows.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/events.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

After doing this, the click event is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does your `console` say? is there any errors present on the console or not?

Comment: no errors..that is why I'm not able to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: if you `console.log` inside the click event handler what happens ?

Comment: click event handler it self is not getting called.

Comment: have you wrapped your code with `document ready`?

Comment: No.. my events.js file contains only the above mentioned code.No other lines

Comment: try wrapping it with `$(function () { .. .. });`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked.